# Push data from aws lambda to redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-lambda

I am trying to create a Lambda function which will connect to RedShift :

```
var pg = require('pg');
var conString = 'postgresql://username:Password@JDBC-URL';
var client = new pg.Client(conString);
client.connect(function(err) { if(err) {
        console.log('could not connect to redshift', err);
    }
    });
pgClient.end();
```

But I am getting this exception :

```
Unable to import module 'index': Error 
at Function.Module._resolve Filename (module.js:325:15) 
at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25) 
at Module.require (module.js:353:17) 
at require (internal/module.js:12:17) 
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:1:72) 
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26) 
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10) 
at Module.load (module.js:343:32) 
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12) 
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
```

Can someone please help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any solution to this yet?

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to push data from AWS Lambda into Amazon Redshift, you could use the **AWS Lambda Redshift Loader**.

See: 
[A Zero-Administration Amazon Redshift Database Loader](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx24VJ6XF1JVJAA/A-Zero-Administration-Amazon-Redshift-Database-Loader)

Answer (score 3):

Another successful approach for loading data into Amazon Redshift from Lambda can be via kinesis firehose[1] which internally can keep data in s3, which inturn is recommended way to load data to redshift instead of insert commands.[2]

Data flow:
Lambda > Firehose (s3) > Redshift.

Further reading suggestions for those who uses this way to save time (even though it is troubleshooting guideline, it can save tonnes of time if read beforehand):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34221861/2406687

Footnotes:

[1] "A COPY command is the most efficient way to load a table. You can also add data to your tables using INSERT commands, though it is much less efficient than using COPY" on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Loading_data.html.

[2] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/what-is-this-service.html