# kinessis is not able to send data to redshift: Redshift.ConnectionFailed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am newbie in aws. there is a week I try to stream data from Nifi to Redshift as test to learn how it work. what I do is that generating a simple record "aa,12,2020" with Nifi send it to kinesis firehose and kinesis send it to s3 bucket and then from there to a table in redshiftcluster.
 I have this error all the time

Redshift.ConnectionFailed

I had try it without nifi with test data from kinesis but the result is the same. 
what I had done til now to resolve the problem is what is writen in this link:
[AWS Kinesis Firehose not inserting data in Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34207317/aws-kinesis-firehose-not-inserting-data-in-redshift)
it is a little more detailed in compare with aws help. 
in this list all things seems to be ok, until

> At this point, you should be able to see the connection attempts in Redshift logs : 
>   `select * from stl_connection_log where remotehost like '52%' order by recordtime desc;

there is any record in my redshift DB.

how much I red, all saying that it is about security and rolls. I think I miss something and I can not find it.
I had 3 times delete all process and make it again, but not helped.
here is my  settings for testing with kinesistestdata:
**Kinesisfirehose:**

- IAM role: firehose_delivery_role
- policies: oneClick_firehose_delivery_role_1586881780618, AmazonRedshiftFullAccess , AmazonS3FullAccess
- Monitoring result:[Monitoring shows Redshift success is zero](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MH0Z7.png)

S3 Bucket:
data file content in bucket:

```
{"ticker_symbol":"AAPL","sector":"TECHNOLOGY","change":0.26,"price":90.78}{"ticker_symbol":"WMT","sector":"RETAIL","change":1.84,"price":95.82}{"ticker_symbol":"CVB","sector":"TECHNOLOGY","change":-0.07,"price":57.51}{"ticker_symbol":"DFT","sector":"RETAIL","change":-0.06,"price":131.62}
```

Object URL-xml file in bucket:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>11111</RequestId>
<HostId>
1111111111111    </HostId>
</Error>
```

**Redshift Cluster:**

- attached IAM Role
  AWSServiceRoleForRedshift 
  firehose_delivery_role (same role in kinesis)
- Network and Security:
  Virtual private cloud (VPC) info
- both CIDR and inbound rules:
  172.31.0.0/16
  13.58.135.96/27
- Availability Zone : us-east-2a
- VPC security group:default
- Publicly accessible: yes

I have read also the Jason pollicies file like: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/controlling-access.html#using-iam-s3
but it is not clear how should I do it. on the other side the policy are added via GUI, so it should work.

would you please help me how should I go step forward?
Thanks alot!

--------some days later-------------

after finding error of copy command I tried to find problem with help of this page:
[s3 access denied 403](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-403/)
I could not find a problem specifically but there is no error in kinesis:redshift log and no error in Redshift database with these 3 query:

```
select * from STL_LOAD_ERRORS;
select * from  STL_FILE_SCAN;
select * from STL_S3CLIENT_ERROR order by recordtime desc;
```

but still no data is coping in redshift.(in kinesis monitoring tab the "DeliveryToRedshift Success " is still on zero)
I will appreciate if anyone has an idea.

Comment: I tried to test my redshift wtih copy command as below:
COPY firehose_test_table FROM 
's3://...file' 
CREDENTIALS 'aws_iam_role=arn:aws:iam::....' MANIFEST JSON'auto'; but it is wierd too. the copy command response successfully but select command shows noting inserted in the database.

Answer (score 1):

first step:
ok, I am a step forward. with this query in redshift, a problem is shows itself

```
select * from STL_S3CLIENT_ERROR order by recordtime desc;
```

the problem is the same: access denied! but it is more resources to search about.
for those who have the same problem as me, these two queries can also be helpfull:

```
select * from STL_LOAD_ERRORS;
select * from  STL_FILE_SCAN;
```

here is the link for more information.
[System tables for troubleshooting data loads](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/system-tables-for-troubleshooting-data-loads.html)

---

second step:
there was some problems with my copy syntax. there is different way to write arn in copy and it is depend on which type of security you like to use. I should write it like this:

```
copy category from 's3://mybucket/testdata/category_pipe.txt'  
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::11111111111'
                    delimiter '|' region 'us-east-2';
```

[here is more information about ARN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-usage_notes-access-permissions.html#copy-usage_notes-iam-permissions)

now my copy example work and I could make connection between redshift and s3 successfully